# Cloth clips through object only at a specific rotation

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision, clipping

so i have this cloth animation, its a plane subdivided 50 times

[image]

and this is what happens when i make it collide against a resized cube (it works as supposed to, no clipping nothing weird

[image]

but if i rotate that same cube, clipping occurs, does anyone know a solution to this?
[image]

blend file:

https://pasteall.org/blend/ae9b0cbb328c41868db2dd209291be0a

Comment: First thing to ever do in cases of weird physics: apply scale.

Comment: if Nathans hint doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: i tried applying the scale on both objects but nothing changed, just added the blend file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings look good, not sure why the cloth gets into the cube and tries then "to crawl over it".

To prevent this go to the *Physics Properties* tab and uncheck *Collision > Softbody & Cloth > `[_]` Single Sided*.

[image: Collison settings]